# Can I visit my fiancée in Kenya during the spouse visa application?

Tags: visas, kenya

Me and my fiancee have been looking to spend time with each other over Christmas in Kenya but I fear that it may negatively affect our spouse visa application in some way, due to speaking to my brother who told me of an issue that happened to a friend of his who was attempting to move to the US which was mucked up because he went to Amsterdam on a stag's do and also was a security concern because of a job he previously worked at, which was a base.

So my question is should I visit my fiancée in Kenya? I am a British citizen and I've been assured that it should be okay but my gut is telling me that it's too iffy.

Comment: For what country are you applying for the spouse visa?

Comment: Your situation seems very different from your brother's friend's. Spending time with your fiancee would tend to support an application for a spouse visa because it is evidence of a genuine relationship. You will need to be sure that the cost of the trip won't impact on any financial requirements for the visa.

Comment: 1. It's for Britain, where we plan to live together, marry, have a family, grow old together. That sort of thing.

Comment: 2. Right. So if I am supposed to earn a requisite amount but it could cause issues later if I don't reach that figure; it could negatively affect our application?

Comment: Mate, wouldn't it be simpler to simply **get married** ?

Comment: I want my family to be there for our marriage rather than having them travelling all the way to Kenya and trying to organise things that way. Besides, the application would still have the same sort of issues such as something that may affect things. Would rather get it done as soon as.

Answer (score 3):

You're a UK citizen and you intend to apply for a [Family visa](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse) so that your fiancée can come to the UK, marry and settle with you in Britain.

It's completely appropriate for you to travel to spend time with her, part of maintaining your relationship, whether before visa application or pending a decision.

As you note, in addition to the relationship, all the eligiblity standards have to be met including income.

Comment: Just to add to this, I went to see my partner in the USA while her visa was being processed. The visa was also approved while I was there which made the trip a lot better as when I had to leave her she was moving to the UK a week or 2 later :)